# How to add variables to database default

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database

I have a rails app and want to add some default text to a field in my database. My schema looks like this:

```
t.text     "message_default", :default => "Thank you"
```

But I want to add some variable to the default:

```
t.text     "message_default", :default => "Thank you Fred"
```

So something like

```
t.text     "message_default", :default => "Thank you #{self.client.name}"
```

I know I can do this with a call_back but I thought it might be quicker (if possible) to add it to the migration as a default (pretty sure it's not possible but I thought I'd ask).

Comment: No you can't… `default` is set on your database and obviously your db can't read ruby variables

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can add defaults to the migration:

```
add_column :table, :call_back, :string, default: 'Thanks - well call you back'
```

First sample in the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html) includes a add_column with default.

Comment: Read my question again. I'm aware you can add a default

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add a default value to your migration using a variable, you need to define the variable in

> config/initializers

if your variable need some logic you can also write an action in your particular initializer `.rb` file

by defining your variable in initializer you can access it in your migration file.

Hope that helps...

Comment: I need the variable to come from end user input when a new user is created

Comment: how is that possible then, you mean when the user provides an input then the migration should run?
I dont think that is possible..

Comment: if you get to know hw it is done plz post the answer here, so that I will also get to know hw it is done..

Answer (score 0):

Better you can use `before_create` call_back to solve this issue

> before_create :set_default
>
> def set_default
>         self.message_default = "Thank you #{self.client.name}"
>    end

I think it will be use full for u?